# Is it possible to make a command that sets the log channel?

Tags: discord.js

I'm creating a new for moderation, and was wondering if it was possible to make a command that sets the log channel, example if they set it to #logs, and if they ban a member it sends a message to #logs Thanks!

I've tried DB, and a support server but no one knew how to create one.

I have tried this:

```
if (command === "ban") {

    if (!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("Error: Insufficient Permissions")

    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(`Error: I have Insufficient Permissions to ban Members`)

    let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    if (!member) return message.channel.send(`Error: Missing Arguments, define member\nUsage: ${prefix}ban [member] [reason]`)

    if (member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS", "KICK_MEMBERS", "MANAGE_SERVER", "ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_MESSAGES", "MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send(`Error: That user is a mod/admin, I can't do that.`)


    if (!member.bannable)
      return message.channel.send(`I cannot ban ${member}`)

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!reason) return message.channel.send(`Error: Missing Arguments, define reason\nUsage: ${prefix}ban [member] [reason]`)

    let log = db.fetch(`channel_${message.guild.id}`)

    if (log === null) return

    let logged = message.guild.channels.get(log)

    member.ban(reason)

    logged.send(`Banned!`)


    message.channel.send(`${member.user.tag} has been successfully banned`)

  }
```

I expected it to send a message to the logged channel.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you create a file for example `setlogchannel.js` where you save the channel on your db i'm pretty sure you using quick.db so you can just copy and paste that code.

```
const {discord, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
let db = require('quick.db')
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
      try {
  message.delete(15000)
  let ads = db.get(`channel_${message.guild.id}`);
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.reply("Nope!").then(m => m.delete(15000));
  if(!args[0]) return message.reply("You should enter a channel");
  if (!ads) {
    db.set(`channel_${message.guild.id}`, args[1])
    return message.reply("Done, the log channel is :", args).then(msg => msg.delete(15000))
  }
     } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Something went wrong!')
        .setColor('RED');
      return message.say(embed).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 15000}));
    }


}
module.exports.help = {
  name: 'setlogchannel',
  aliases: ['slc']
};
```

And on your `index.js` you just verify if it exists if it does then you just send it to that channel

```
if (command === "ban") {

    if (!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("Error: Insufficient Permissions")

    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send(`Error: I have Insufficient Permissions to ban Members`)

    let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    if (!member) return message.channel.send(`Error: Missing Arguments, define member\nUsage: ${prefix}ban [member] [reason]`)

    if (member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS", "KICK_MEMBERS", "MANAGE_SERVER", "ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_MESSAGES", "MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send(`Error: That user is a mod/admin, I can't do that.`)

    if (!member.bannable)
      return message.channel.send(`I cannot ban ${member}`)

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!reason) return message.channel.send(`Error: Missing Arguments, define reason\nUsage: ${prefix}ban [member] [reason]`)

    let log = db.fetch(`channel_${message.guild.id}`)

    if (log) {
    let logged = message.guild.channels.get(log)
    logged.send(`Banned!`)
    }
    member.ban(reason)
    message.channel.send(`${member.user.tag} has been successfully banned`)

  }
```

Comment: On my side it worked, can you explain what didn't work more specificly

Comment: Sorry, for such a poor response,I'm using discord.js and usally; i do message.channel.send not message.say, along the embed too i use let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed();
and i went though a whole support server, and haven't found out how to work it.

Comment: How is that related to your question? Can you show any error logs